# Undefined method class::construct() when creating a plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, oop

I try to create a simple plugin following by the guid http://docs.layerswp.com/plugin-creation-guide

So I've created main file **functions.php**

```
<?php /*
* Plugin Name: Layers - Demo Extension
* Version: 1.0
* Plugin URI: http://www.yourpluginpage.com
* Description: What does your Extension do for Layers?
* Author: You
* Author URI: http://www.yoursite.com/
*
* Requires at least: 4.5
* Tested up to: 4.5.3
*
* Layers Plugin: True
* Layers Required Version: 1.5.4
*
* Text Domain: layers-demo-plugin
* Domain Path: /lang/
*/
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// define constants (optional)

// Load plugin class files
require_once( 'includes/class-layers-demo-extension.php' );

// Instantiate Plugin
function layers_demo_extension_init() {
    global $layers_demo_extension;
    $layers_demo_extension = Layers_Demo_Extension::get_instance();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'layers_demo_extension_init' );

// Additional Functionality
```

and the file **includes/class-layers-demo-extension.php**

```
<?php /**
* Layers Demo Extension
*
* What your plugin does
*
* @package Layers
* @since Layers 1.2.4
*/

class Layers_Demo_Extension {

//Initiator
private static $instance;

public static function get_instance() {
    if ( ! self::$instance ) {
        self::$instance = new self();
        self::$instance->construct();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

// Constructor
private function __construct() {
    // Hooks go here
}

//Custom Functions

}
```

But when I go to admin panel, I get the 500 error.

When I enable `WP_DEBUG` I see this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Layers_Demo_Extension::construct() in /.../wp-content/plugins/layers-demo-extension/includes/class-layers-demo-extension.php:18 Stack trace:
#0 /.../wp-content/plugins/layers-demo-extension/functions.php(29): Layers_Demo_Extension::get_instance()
#1 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): layers_demo_extension_init('')
#2 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /.../wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /.../wp-settings.php(327): do_action('plugins_loaded')
#5 /.../wp-config.php(89): require_once('...')
#6 /.../wp-load.php(37): require_once('...')
#7 /.../wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('...')
#8 /.../wp-admin/tools.php(10): in /.../wp-content/plugins/layers-demo-extension/includes/class-layers-demo-extension.php on line 18
```

But I don't know how to fix the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get_instance()` method, you call `self::$instance->construct()` not `self::$instance->__construct()`. Also, there's no reason to call the constructor like that; it will be called when you invoke `new self()`;